# What.NET parsing technologies are available that would let me build a a custom expression evaluator?

Tags: c#, antlr, expression-trees

I need to generate an IQueryable LINQ expression from a string.  First examine class **Foo**

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Method **ToFoo** would then take anything inside **{}** and return an IQueryable list.

So `ToFoo("{1, >, 10}")` would return an IQueryable list.  I have this part working already.  What I'm missing is the Parsing method to combine the various IQueryable objects.

```
IQueryable<Foo> context = GetAllFoos(....);
string myInput = "({e1} | ({e2} & {e3})) | {e4}";
var result = SomeParser(myInput, context);
foreach(var x in result)
   WriteLine(x.Bar);
```

The only allowable operations would be **&** (Intersect) and **|** Union.

So in the example above SomeParser would return something like:

```
result = ToFoo("{e1}").Union(
                    ToFoo("{e2}").Intersect(ToFoo("{e3}")
                    ).Union(ToFoo("{e4}");
```

I was looking at ANTLR, but I'm unsure if this would require Java, which is a non-starter for deployment reasons.  But I'm not sure if ANTLR would allow me to define my grammar and would build my c# classes, thus not having to require Java installed on the target systems.

In any case, it looks like I need to build an expression tree where I can navigate through the structure and UNION/INTERSECT the results returned from `ToFoo`

Comment: You can write a recursive descent parser, build your own AST and climb over to generate code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769  I can't tell from your question whether you need to resolve names to definitions to do your task; if you do, a parser will be of very little actual help, because he name resolution part is much harder.  (See my essay on "Life After Parsing" at my bio for more details).

Comment: ANTLR requires java at build time only, it doesn't need it to be installed on target machines.

Comment: Echoing @IraBaxter's question: What does `{e1}` mean? Is that some representation of a Foo object? A list of Foo objects?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PEG parser https://code.google.com/p/peg-sharp/ - it's quite simple and doesn't require bothering with all those "tokenizers" - it works directly with source.